# How to create a netbeans client for a wso2 service

Tags: netbeans, client, wso2

I am trying to create a client for a service that is running on WSO2, but doesn't working, anyone know any tutorial? I'm trying to use the ?WSDL but netbeans doesn't parse the WSDL correctly.

Comment: Which WSDL are you tying to parse?  Can you give more details on the parsing problem?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html) is an example explaining how to generate web service client from WSDL. You could also generate it using Axis2 and it's standalone wsdl2java tool. [Here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) is the documentation of wsdl2java tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 Developer Studio to generate the Web Service client from your WSDL file. Please refer [Developer Studio documentation](http://wso2.org/project/developer-studio/2.0.1/docs/axis2_jaxws_category.html#Axis2Utils2) for more information.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana